# Unable to read a true when using array value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

UPDATE(11 Aug 22): Per request from Ruben - The checkboxes are placed next to a column of items using  `.insertCheckboxes()`. They are checked when `onEdit(e)` is invoked by any entry in the checkbox column. Temporarily the checkbox status is listed next to each item to ensure that the checkbox value is changing. The desired outcome is to capture which checkbox is `true` so that item can be edited on the associated data entry form. The non-working code is part of a if/else statement. The if works fine, which indicates to me that the logic is OK:

```
  if (newAssetBox === true) {
    gatherAsset();
  }
```

But the `else` statement does NOT work. As you can see below, it is using a counter thru an array to get and list the checkbox value. I have removed the `//` lines from the original posting for clarity.
Hope this helps better understand the problem.

ORIGINAL POST:
In this function the first if for newAssetBoxs() works just fine.
But `if (theCheckedBoxs[count] === true)`  does not work (the block of code is temporary for trouble shooting purposes). The function is called by an OnEdit(). I have tried many ways and am totally frustrated.
You can see in the second block of code below that I can display the value of the checked box as true just fine (the boxs are between the TRUE/FALSE and the descriptive text) . Please offer some suggestions. Thanks

```
function checkTheBoxs() {
  assetEntryForm.getRange("F2").clearContent();
  if (newAssetBox === true) {
    gatherAsset();
  } else {
    for (count = 0; count < 20; count++) {
      assetEntryForm.getRange(count + 3, 10, 1, 1).setValue(theCheckedBoxs[count]);
      if (theCheckedBoxs[count] === true) {                  
        assetEntryForm.getRange("F2").setValue('Found a True');
      } else {
        editAsset();

      }
    }
  }
```

The following block is a partial from the form page. The checkbox, not shown, but there on the form between TRUE and XLR is the only one checked.

```
FALSE   AC / Power cables   
TRUE    XLR type cable
FALSE   Multi Pair cables
FALSE   NL4 cable   
FALSE   NL8 speaker cables
FALSE   L14-30 10/4 cable
FALSE   Behringer S16 Digital Snake with 100 Foot DuraCat6 Cable
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (include the theCheckedBoxs declaration as well some sample data and the expected results)

Comment: I'm glad that you was able to find the solution by yourself. Regarding the edit made, it's not necessary to add something like `UPDATE(11 Aug 22)` as each post has a edit history, and the post shows the last time that it was updated. P.S. the `checkedBoxs` declaration was not included.

Answer (score 0):

I finally returned to this problem and logger.logged the `theCheckedBoxs[count]` to discover that it is actually a 2d array (why I am not sure). I was getting `[true}` instead of `true`, so I searched around and found that flat() will convert 2D to 1D and bingo, now I find my true with `theCheckedBoxs.flat()[count]` and life is good again...